# SSDP Discovery service unexpectedly stops

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-media-player, dlna, upnp

I discovered this problem as my UPnP device (a Sony Bravia tv) constantly lost connection with the Windows Media Player sharing server (used as the DLNA media server for the Sony TV and apparently depends on the SSDP and UPnP services).

I've started investigating the issue and using the Event Viewer I noticed that every time I start the SSDP service, and exactly after 10.00 minutes, it unexpectedly and undesirably stops.

For sure this causes the disconnection between the TV and my PC and stops the streaming.

What could be the reason for that? How can i further investigate to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: On Event Viewer, when the service stops, is stops folowed by an error? There are some warning or error events related to the service or even another error events at the same time?

Comment: No errors or warnings following or preceding this event or related to the service... actually, i notice that a service named Multimedia Class Scheduler is also alternately stopping and starting around the start\stop of the SSDP service